# Asp.net 5 plesk IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-core, plesk

I developed an asp.net 5 application that works in local IIS.

- I installed .net dnx via dnvm
- httpplatformhandler 1.2 for IIS

But in server there is plesk. I create the domain from plesk and try to publish the site in there.

After creating the domain I setted root folder to "wwwroot" of my published project. When I try to open the website in browser it just wait for connection. Does not return anything at all.

When I put index.html file only it works.

Plesk creates a user for application pool. I also gave it to read write permissions to all directories.

If I change the application pool user to something else like network service it just gives 500 internal error with no decription.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as  "a problem that can no longer be reproduced". Current steps for publishing into IIS are described in docs: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

Comment: I wish that document solved that. I had to turn back mvc5 instead.